# Pagination is not getting centered?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have made pagination component but not able to center it on Home page.
I tried various CSS styling but pagination is not centered it always appear on left on Home page.

pagination.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Pagination extends Component {

    handleClick(val){
    this.setState({
        end:val*16,
        start:end-16
    });
    const end = val*16;
    this.props.onChange(end - 16, end);
    }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1)}>1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 2)}>2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 3)}>3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 4)}>4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 5)}>5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Pagination;
```

pagination.css:

```
.pagination {
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    font-size:11px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I also tried this styling :

```
.pagination {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: try > .container > text-align: center ; .pagination > display: inline-block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check carefully other overriding css, centering pagination is just that simple:

```css
ul li {
display: inline-block;
}


.container{
 background: red;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">                 
              <ul className="pagination">
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1)}>1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 2)}>2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 3)}>3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 4)}>4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 5)}>5</a></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `flexbox` like this:

```
.pagination {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.pagination li {
  display: block;
 }
```

A working example here: https://codepen.io/crysfel/pen/gvaxWv

Answer (score 0):

This Code works for me perfectly

```
.pagination {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

Comment: I dont know why exactly , i used bootstrap to make pagination and it worked good but when i convert it to wordpress , it doesnt centered the pagination till i used this code and then everything centered ...Do you know why exactly this code workds ? i would like to know why too , i'm a beginner @cmprogram